# CSS type casting? How to add "px" and "rem" using calc()?

Tags: css

Assume I have variables with the following values: `32px` and `1rem`. I need to combine the two values and set, say, `font-size` in `rem` units. How is that done?

This does not work: `font-size: calc(32px + 1rem);`

In the scenario given, I actually want to set the font-size to `3rem`. In my mind, the first step would be for me to convert `32px` to its `rem` equivalent and then add the `1rem` that I have (so, something like `calc(32px / 16) + 1rem)`). That doesn't work, either.

Is there a way to convert the 32px to its `rem` equivalent?

Comment: So you want to convert "32px" to "3rem" inside your css and not browser-sided? Cause `calc(32px + 1rem)` does work in the browser, it doesnt convert to (4rem) tho but the browser dynamically calculates the value.

Comment: What's your base font-size? Rest of the rems works on base font-size value only. and may I ask the reason behind complicating a very simple thing in CSS?

Comment: I'm assuming that 16px = 1rem. So, 32px + 1rem = 3rem.  @richa_pandey - how would you simplify my problem?

Comment: before giving any solution, I would like to know the problem first.

Comment: Didn't I give the problem? How do you add `32px` and `1rem` using `calc()`?

Comment: You cannot do this with calc(), as simple as that

Comment: @TemaniAfif - I was able to convert a number like `100` to something with a unit, like `px`, by doing this: `calc(100 * 1px)`. Really no option in this scenario?

Comment: this is not a conversion, it's a multiplication of 1px by 100 to make it 100px (a simple math formula)

Comment: @TemaniAfif - can you please put your comment down as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

For converting with [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) simply multiply your conversion formula by 1 of the desired unit. Since you want to convert a pixel value to rem, you can do this: `calc(32 / 16 * 1rem)`

Answer (score -2):

The standard root font-size is 1rem=16px, if you didn't change it

If you are using saas (.scss) you can create a simple function and use it:

```
@function px-to-rem($px) {
  $root-font-size: 16; // Adjust the root font-size accordingly
  @return #{$px / $root-font-size}rem;
}

.my-class {
  font-size: calc(#{px-to-rem(32)} + 1rem);
}
```

Good luck!